# cross-domain call never getting jsonp callback appended

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, couchdb, jsonp

I am attempting to do a GET request to pull documents from CouchDB. I am getting the typical "xmlhttprequest cannot load..." error that you get with cross-domain requests. However, this error persists even when I create a jQuery.ajax object and set its datatype to jsonp and crossdomain to true. It appears it is never appending any callback to my url.

Code:

```
var ajaxOptions = new $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5984/',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
```

I then call jquery.couch.js to retrieve the document and format the url:

```
$.couch.db(options.dbName).openDoc(docId, options, ajaxOptions);
```

Any obvious problems?

Comment: Why do you have the `new` in `new $.ajax({`?

Comment: Where's the callback funtion (that JSONP uses) ?

Comment: crossDomain: true isn't needed, fyi. What you have should work (minus the `new`)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the jquery ajax parameters I needed should be set in the ajaxOptions part of the call to jquery.couch. So it looks like this (and works):

```
$.couch.db(options.dbName).openDoc(docId, options, {
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Passing the ajaxOptions as a function takes the place of creating a jquery.ajax object myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ajax request like

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : 'http://localhost:5984/',
  dataType : "jsonp",
  contentType : "application/json",
  success : function(data) {
    //function body
  }
});
```

Comment: `contentType: application/json` is ignored with jsonp and script datatypes

Comment: `contentType` is the `Content-Type` ***sent*** to the server in the AJAX ***request***.  It's wrong here.